# Number of important Windows Updates

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-update, automatic-updates

For Microsoft Server OS's, is there a location in the registry or possibly WMI that stores the number of pending Important Updates?

My inventory software supports wmi and registry keys. Trying to see if there is a way to report that number so that I know remotely if there are updates either ready to be downloaded/installed. Searching for this gives a lot of out of scope information since ther are generic terms.

While I do use WSUS this information would be preferential to have centralized in my LanSweeper inventory system. Neglected to mention that I use WSUS yes. For WSUS to have this information I would gather that is it locally on my machine as well.

Comment: What's wrong with WSUS?  You *do*, at least use WSUS, don't you?

Comment: WSUS has had this functionality for almost a decade now, probably the more robust solution.

Comment: @DavidV Added an update to give my situation more context. Thanks. WSUS does have this info just not where I need it.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you to extract it from the registry/wmi - it will only tell you about updates windows knows about, so automatic checking for updates will need to be on and have run recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible to find the number of pending important updates.  But in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UAS` there is a Key called `UpdateCount` that will give you the total number of pending updates.

Comment: Hrm, this key doesn't seem to be present on the Windows 8 and 2012r2 machine I have at my desk.

Comment: I don't have a Windows 8 or r2 machine near me to check, but I have it in Win7, 2008r2, and 2012.

Comment: Sorry forgot we have some 8.1 dev machines, can confirm it exists there as well.

Comment: I need to check some more systems but this would suffice for my needs. If the number is greater than 0 I hope it represents work I have to do on that system.

Answer (score 6):

There are 4 registry keys that will let you know if there are pending updates. HopelessN00b was on the right track, though you have to go up one level to see the keys.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update
```

The keys you want are:

- `UpdatesAvailableForDownloadLogon` - Updates pending download(important updates)
- `UpdatesAvailableForInstallLogon` - Downloaded updates pending install
- `UpdatesAvailableWithUiLogon` - Pending updates that need interaction to install
- `UpdatesAvailableWithUiOrEulaLogon` - Similar to above but you also have to accept a EULA

This should do the trick for your inventory software. Another one I tweak remotely is; NextDetectionTime
This way if it is not going to check WU for a while or a security patch is out that I want to grab, I edit the date to today and the current time +1 minute.

Comment: I will look at these to see if they fit my needs. Welcome to SF